# Regex for replacing tags

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace string like this

```
@@colored:some_text @color:clr@@
```

with the following html tag:

```
<p style='color:clr;'>some_text</P>
```

I wrote a regular expression for searching such text fragments but I am at a loss how to do substitution. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/gM5gQ5/1) is an example of my regex

Here is an example of my C# code where I try to do it

```
    private string Colored(string data)
    {
        var colorMatches = Regex.Matches(data, "@@colored:(.|\n)*? @color:(.*?)@@");
        if (colorMatches.Count == 0)
            return data;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var matches = new List<Match>();
        sb.Append(Regex.Replace(data, @"@@colored:(.|\n)*? @color:(.*?)@@", match =>
        {
            // i don't know how to replace text properly
        }));

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Please help me to do text substitution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://regex101.com/r/kB1qR7/1)?

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/98713)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` lets you use `$<number>` syntax to refer to values captured by *capturing groups* defined in your regex for substitution. Your call of `Replace` would look like this:

```
Regex.Replace(
    data
,   @"@@colored:((?:.|\n)*?) @color:(.*?)@@"
,   @"<p style='$2;'>$1</p>"
)
```

`$2` refers to the content of the `(.*?)` capturing group; `$1` refers to the content of `((?:.|\n)*?)`. Note the use of non-capturing parentheses `(?: ...)` for grouping without creating a capturing group. This could cause significant slowdowns due to *backtracking*, though, so you need to be very careful with it. See [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) for ways to deal with the problem.

Comment: This `(?:.|\n)*?` should be avoided as often as possible due to the number of backtracking steps it generates. Even with short strings, it may cause catastrophic backtracking easily.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the lazy dot matching subpattern into the first capturing group (first set of unescaped parentheses):

```
(?s)@@colored:(.*?) @color:(.*?)@@
```

Note that for the `.` to match a newline, you need to use a *singleline modifier* (either inline `(?s)` or `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag).

And use the `<p style='color:$2;'>$1</p>` substitution where `$1` refers the `some_text`, and `$2` refers to the `color`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW1mK0/1), and here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/bbZdSR):

```
var str = "some text @@colored:South Africa, officially the Republic of South Africa, is the southernmost country in Africa. It is bounded on the south by 2,798 kilometers of coastline of southern Africa stretching along the South Atlantic and Indian Oceans on the north by the neighbouring countries of Namibia, Botswana and Zimbabwe, and on the east by Mozambique and Swaziland, and surrounding the kingdom of Lesotho.[12] South Africa is the 25th-largest country in the world by land area, and with close to 53 million people, is the world's 24th-most populous nation. @color:red@@ another text";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, @"(?s)@@colored:(.*?) @color:(.*?)@@", "<p style='color:$2;'>$1</p>"));
```

And my usual **warning**: lazy dot matching may cause a code execution freeze with very large input. To avoid it, use unroll-the-loop technique:

```
@@colored:([^ ]*(?: (?!@color:)[^ ]*)*) @color:([^@]*(?:@(?!@)[^@]*)*)@@
```

This regex has another *advantage*: it does not require a singleline modifier to match newline symbols. See [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/bW1mK0/2).